# Can't run tensorflow GPU with Anaconda due to bus error

Tags: linux, python-3.x, tensorflow, anaconda, nvidia

I was correctly working with tensorflow GPU 1.8.0 on Python 3.6 (Anaconda) with CUDA 9.2 and linux. My GPU is Nvidia Geforce GTX Titan (6GB)

Then one day I tried to run my script and I got a `Bus error (core dumped)` error. After tracking it down, I get this error after importing `sklearn` or executing some tensorflow functions. Same scripts that used to work fine now are not working anymore.

When I use `gdb python` and then execute my script with `r main.py`, I get the next debugging error information:

```
Thread 1 "python" received signal SIGBUS, Bus error.
0x00007ffece4d5970 in PyInit__arpack ()
   from /home/user/anaconda3/envs/py361/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/eigen/arpack/_arpack.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

This also happened before. In that case, importing `cv2` didn't work with python3 but then I managed to make it work with python2. Finally I reinstalled linux and it worked for some time until the previously shown error began happening.

How could I fix this?

Comment: A bus error is usually due to a misaligned address. On x86 they are frequent when using the SSE vector unit. It looks like `_arpack.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` or your program is not respecting alignment requirements. You probably need to build `_arpack.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` and your program with full symbols and `-O3` to ensure vectorization (`-O3` kind of sucks in this case). Then you can work back from the faulting ASM instruction to the C source code.

Comment: *"... I reinstalled linux and it worked for some time until the previously shown error began happening."* - It sounds like you were just getting lucky for a while. Does `-Wcast-align` produce any warnings when building the shared object or your program? Are all the objects that get shipped off to the SSE vector unit aligned on 16-byte boundaries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled anaconda and it's working again.